# React: how to load different api on different button click

Tags: reactjs

I need to load different API urls on different button click:

Here is the API Component:

```
const companiesUrl = "http://localhost:3005/local-companies-xxx";

class Companies extends Component {
    state = {
        companyDetails: [],
        currentPage: 0
    };


    get items() {
        const {currentPage, companiesDetails} = this.state;
        return companiesDetails.slice(currentPage * 3, currentPage * 3 + 3)
    }

    changeCurrentPage = (i) => {
        this.setState({
            currentPage : i
        })
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(companiesUrl)
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(info => this.setState({companiesDetails: info}))
            .catch(error => console.error("error connecting to the api"));
    } 
 [more code... removed because not really necessary to show right now]
```

Here is the button Component:

```
class HomeButton extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="button" onClick={this.props.passClick}>
                <p>{this.props.buttonText}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
export default HomeButton;
```

And here is the Parent:

```
class WhomWeHelp extends Component {
    state = {
        count : 0
    };

    increment() {
        this.setState({
            count : this.state.count + 1
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <section>
                <div>
                    <HomeButton buttonText="xxx" passClick={this.increment} />
                    <HomeButton buttonText="yyy" passClick={this.increment} />
                    <HomeButton buttonText="zzzz" passClick={this.increment} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Companies />
                </div>


            </section>
        )
    }
}


export default WhomWeHelp;
```

As you can see I tried to add an `onClick={this.props.passClick}` to the button Component and pass the click to the Parent with `passClick={this.increment}` so that it runs the method

```
increment() {
    this.setState({
        count : 0
    })
}
```

Then I wanted to transfer this state to the API Component and load a different API Url per different button.
Button xxx should load the api with an xxx url, button yyy should load the yyy companies, and zzz the zzz companies.

However right now when I click the 3 buttons I get `WhomWeHelp.jsx:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined at increment...`

Why I am getting such error? If instead of this.setstate, I put a console log inside `increment() {}` it works fine.

Also is there a better way to achieve what I am doing avoiding to pass the click from child to parent, and then to pass the state from parent to API child?

Thanks

Comment: Try binding `increment` in your constructor. (`this.increment = this.increment.bind(this)`). That should fix your `cannot read property 'setState'` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If when you put a `console.log` inside `increment`, it works fine, then I would say your `this` is the problem and your `this` is probably `undefined`. I imagine it is a scope issue.

Try changing your `increment` function to an arrow function expression like this:

```
  increment = () => { 
    this.setState((state) => ({
      count: state.count + 1
    }));
  }
```

For the issue of sending different API requests for different button clicks, you can create another arrow function expression as the binding event and send a flag to determine which API should be hit for each button. For example:

```
 <button onClick={() => this.increment("xxx")}>xxx</button>
```

Check this reproducible example out where every button does something different to update the state:

[image: Edit pedantic-swartz-0s74r]

Comment: thank you, it works, the counter increases. How can I give a different state per button? I need to differentiate those clicks. Those 3m btns are the same component

Comment: What do you mean by a different state per button? Do you a counter for every button? In that case, I would create, inside the same state, three counters, such as `this.state = {counterOne: 0, counterTwo: 0, counterThree: 0}`.

Comment: The counter was just a test to make the buttons work. What I need is to pass some argument to the API Component, where I will make an IF and load a differe URL per different state.
The state would be `entity: xxx` or `entity: yyy` or `entity: zzz`. Is the only way to create 3 different methods per each button (instead of the increment() metod)?

Comment: I updated my answer. Check if that suits your needs.

Comment: I think we are near. When I add ("xxx") to `passClick={this.increment("xxx")` I get `Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

Comment: Instead of passing a function, you're calling your function in your `passClick={this.increment("xxx")}`. Instead of that, you should create an arrow function such as `passClick={() => this.increment("xxx")}`.